# cocos2dx Windows Phone 10 game graphic quality

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, cocos2d-x

I am trying to clone a game for Windows phone. This is not for commerical. 
I've created new cocos2dx win10 project with cocos creator. And tried to build and executed on Windows Phone 10 Lumia 935. But when I execute on real device, the graphic quality is lower than the original one. The 2 screenshots were attached.
I've setted screen resoulution to 800 x 480. And all images are not scaled.

[image]

This is the image on original game.

[image]

And this is the image on my new game.

Why these 2 image quality is different?

The original image is this.

[image]

What's the reason? I've read this article, but still not found correct answer.
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/issues/15901

The codes that I've implemented was added.

```
auto director = Director::getInstance();
    auto glview = director->getOpenGLView();
    if(!glview) {
#if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_WIN32) || (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_MAC) || (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_LINUX)
        glview = GLViewImpl::createWithRect("RealHillClimb", cocos2d::Rect(0, 0, designResolutionSize.width, designResolutionSize.height));
#else
        glview = GLViewImpl::create("RealHillClimb");
#endif
        director->setOpenGLView(glview);
    }
    director->setAnimationInterval(1.0f / 180);
    glview->setDesignResolutionSize(1280, 720, ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER);
    auto frameSize = glview->getFrameSize();
    int a = Device::getDPI();
    if (frameSize.height > mediumResolutionSize.height)
    {        
        director->setContentScaleFactor(MIN(largeResolutionSize.height/designResolutionSize.height, largeResolutionSize.width/designResolutionSize.width));
    }
    else if (frameSize.height > smallResolutionSize.height)
    {        
        director->setContentScaleFactor(MIN(mediumResolutionSize.height/designResolutionSize.height, mediumResolutionSize.width/designResolutionSize.width));
    }
    else
    {        
        director->setContentScaleFactor(MIN(smallResolutionSize.height/designResolutionSize.height, smallResolutionSize.width/designResolutionSize.width));
    }
    director->setContentScaleFactor(1);
    cocos2d::Size dsize = glview->getDesignResolutionSize(); 
    float d = director->getContentScaleFactor();
    register_all_packages();    
    auto scene = SCNSplash::createScene();
    director->runWithScene(scene);
    return true;
```

Comment: I am thinking that it may be because of the way  you manage multi resolutions on your project. Can you add the the part of your code where you set your design resolution and the part where you handling multi resolution. (including what resolution policy you are using.) that might help us to identify the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your visiting. I've added codes to the above. Please check it and explain me what I have missed.

Comment: I don't understand the reason you call the director->setContentScaleFactor(1) after determining the large medium and small texture size within the if else statement. your issue might be fixed by as simple as removing the director->setContentScaleFactor(1);  After all you determining the content scale factor within the if else conditional statement after that you hardcode it to 1. which makes the entire if else condition pointless.